# KMPlayer does not open any video

Tags: video-player, mplayer

I installed KMPlayer using `sudo apt-get install kmplayer` on Ubuntu 22.04 but I can't open any video. Why?

Comment: Open a terminal in the directory of the video, and run the command `kmplayer name-of-video-file.extension`. Edit the question and post the output.

Comment: Thank you. But now just open km-player and do not show video.